# Excel: Find first time in multiple common dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

**Editing my original question** as the requirement has changed:

If the source table is like below:

[image]

Need the result as below table:

[image]

Basically, remove all other data other than for each date the first occurrence of an event for the respective date.

Comment: By "first" do you mean chronologically first, or the first item found? If the latter, or if the data is sorted, a simple vlookup should do the trick. In any case, you'd be better off storing date and time as a single field.

Comment: Not working. Expanding sorting also won't work, because what I need is for (from above example images) date 13th I need the first occurring time which is 11:50 AM, for date 14th first occurring time is 1:20 PM etc. I also need to delete all other data falling in other category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask for formulas, so try these:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$13,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$13),0))
```

Formula in `E2`:

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=D2,$B$2:$B$13,""))
```

Drag down...

> ***Important:*** Enter both formulas as array through
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Excellent ! Working as expected. Thank you so much.

Comment: Any other method other than using formulas? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @dev646, for sure: Select range > Sort > 1st level: Sort on Date, old to new > 2nd level: Sort on Time, small to large > Keep range selected > Remove duplicates > Check Date > Uncheck Time > Confirm

Comment: Thanks a lot. The requirement has changed and updated the same in post.

Answer (score 0):

Got it... Basically derived from the JvDV's answer.
Step1: Add one column to find the duplicates in number column and apply the formula:

> =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2)>1, "Duplicate", "")

Step 2: expand the sorting first from lowest to largest number
Step 3: expand the sorting second date wise from old to new 
and as step 3: expand sorting time-wise from old to new

Then delete the rows containing duplicates by filtering it out and remove the filter to see results.